# Loop to check for duplicate strings

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I want to create a loop to check a list of titles for duplicates.

I currently have this:

```
var productTitles = SeleniumContext.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(ComparisonTableElements.ProductTitle));

foreach (var x in productTitles)
{
    var title = x.Text;

    productTitles = SeleniumContext.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(ComparisonTableElements.ProductTitle));

    foreach (var y in productTitles.Skip(productTitles.IndexOf(x) + 1))
    {
        if (title == y.Text)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Found duplicate product in the table");
        }
    }
}
```

But this is taken the item I skip out of the array for the next loop so item 2 never checks it's the same as item 1, it moves straight to item 3.

I was under the impression that skip just passed over the index you pass in rather than removing it from the list.

Comment: I believe skip will skip over 'N' number of elements. So if you want to ignore the first element then you Skip(1)... and so on.

Comment: GroupBy will do everything in a line. If possible use Linq

Comment: I would like to be able to skip the element in the first loop so it doesn't do a check against itself if that makes sense. So item 1 checks against all elements apart from 1, item 2 checks against item 1,3,4,5 etc

Comment: skip doesnt remove..

Comment: Use GroupBy and filter where group.Count() > 1.  Skip literally skips the given number of records. It doesn't skip an index position. And, who cares, because if you compare each item in order, you never need to backtrack. If you check 1 against 2, you don't need to re-check 2 against 1.  Same goes for 3, 4, etc.

Comment: _var g = productTitles.GroupBy(x => x).Where(y => y.Count() > 1); foreach(var x in g) Console.WriteLine(x.Key);_

Comment: @BrianMitchell - Are you trying to generate a distinct list or do you need to know and act upon any duplicates found?

Comment: Why are you remaking the group productTitles again in the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var anyDuplicates = SeleniumContext
    .Driver
    .FindElements(By.XPath(ComparisonTableElements.ProductTitle))
    .GroupBy(p => p.Text, p => p)
    .Any(g => g.Count() > 1);

Assert.That(anyDuplicates, Is.False);
```

or [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var productTitles = SeleniumContext
    .Driver
    .FindElements(By.XPath(ComparisonTableElements.ProductTitle))
    .Select(p => p.Text)
    .ToArray();

var distinctProductTitles = productTitles.Distinct().ToArray();

Assert.AreEqual(productTitles.Length, distinctProductTitles.Length);
```

Or, if it is enough to find a first duplicate without counting all of them it's better to use a [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var titles = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (var title in SeleniumContext
    .Driver
    .FindElements(By.XPath(ComparisonTableElements.ProductTitle))
    .Select(p => p.Text))
{
    if (!titles.Add(title))
    {
        Assert.Fail("Found duplicate product in the table");
    }
}
```

All approaches are better in terms of computational complexity (O(n)) than what you propose (O(n<sup>2</sup>)).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a loop. Simply use the `Where()` function to find all same titles, and if there is more than one, then they're duplicates:

```
var productTitles = SeleniumContext.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(ComparisonTableElements.ProductTitle));

foreach(var x in productTitles) {
  if (productTitles.Where(y => x.Text == y.Text).Count() > 1) {
    Assert.Fail("Found duplicate product in the table");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try a slightly different way since you only need to check for duplicates in a one-dimensional array.

You only have to check the previous element with the next element within the array/collection so using `Linq` to iterate through all of the items seems a bit unnecessary.

Here's a piece of code to better understand:

```
var productTitles = SeleniumContext.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(ComparisonTableElements.ProductTitle))

for ( int i = 0; i < productionTitles.Length; i++ )
{
    var currentObject = productionTitles[i];
    for ( int j = i + 1; j < productionTitles.Length; j++ )
    {
        if ( currentObject.Title == productionTitles[j].Title )
        {
            // here's your duplicate
        }
    }
}
```

Since you've checked that item at index 0 is not the same as item placed at index 3 there's no need to check that again when you're at index 3. The items will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

The `Skip(IEnumerable, n)` method returns an IEnumerable that doesn't "contain" the n first element of the IEnumerable it's called on.

Also I don't know what sort of behaviour could arise from this, but I wouldn't assign a new IEnumerable to the variable over which the foreach is being executed.

Here's another possible solution with LINQ:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var x in productTitles)
{
    var possibleDuplicate = productTitles.Skip(i++).Find((y) => y.title == x.title);

    //if possibleDuplicate is not default value of type
        //do stuff here
}
```

This goes without saying, but the best solution for you will depend on what you are trying to do. Also, I think the `Skip` method call is more trouble than it's worth, as I'm pretty sure it will most certainly make the search less eficient.